# Multiple Tier Preferences in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences

Right now I have a PreferenceActivity and a PreferenceFragment. The activity just has onBuildHeaders defined, and it loads an XML file that has a root object of preference-headers and then several children of it which are headers. Each header points at the PreferenceFragment and an XML file containing the screens, categories, and preferences.

The issue is, this system only goes 2 layers deep. There's the headers on the left panel, and then everything for that header is in a single list on the right panel. For some headers, there's only a dozen or so options so it works okay. For other headers, there's 100+ preferences, which is fairly overwhelming, both to scroll and scan through, as well as for the device to load (there's a noticeable delay between tapping to open and having it open.)

Is there any way I can have multiple tiers? I figure on the left the user will be able to "drill down" (mostly a term I've heard with iOS, IDK how common a term it is with Android) through headers until they reach the level where the preferences are actually stored and have that display on the right panel?

Writing my own completely custom system seems feasible, but time consuming. I'm hoping someone knows of some built in APIs that will implement 3 or 4 tier drill down preferences for me.

And before anyone asks, yes, I do need to have this many preferences (~500). I have been instructed to make the preference menu and given the list of items (which can be categorized into 3 or 4 tiers pretty easily.)

Comment: 500 seems a lot of preferences to have. Why not simply break those preferences in even smaller groups and use the current system?

Comment: My top items are "General", "Personalize", "Data Collection", "Graph", "Configure", and "About". Configure is the one that really needs to be broken down. It contains over 300 preferences, which I could break down into ~20 categories. While it's true I could add those 20 categories to the top list, it seems like it'd be odd to have "General", "Personalize", "Data Collection", "Graph", 20 different "Configure (name)", and an "About". I'd much rather the user select "Configure", then see the list of things they can Configure, and then set the preferences for each thing.

Comment: The Settings part of an app should be something simple, not something to overwhelm the user(exactly what is going to happen when the user will have to choose from a gazillion options). You don't have to give names as Configure (name) just use a representative name for those specific grouped settings. If you insist with your initial goal, I would make a normal activity and build it like I want with levels.

Comment: The built in Settings app does exactly what I want. If you have a ~10" screen, it'll show a column of headings on the left, like my app. Touch a heading, say "Date & Time", and it gives me a column of subheadings on the right. Select one of those subheadings and it'll replace the list of subheadings on the right with a list of settings for that subheading. All I want to know is how I should organize my app's files to have it do that. I have the two columns already. Having Preference Screens on the left causes the whole screen to be replaced, not just the fragment. Categories list prefs below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually pretty easy. In the XML file that the root headers open, I added in a Preference item and set android:fragment to be of my PreferencesFragment class. To clarify how my entire system works I have:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> targer) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }
```

preference_headers then looks like this:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <header android:fragment="com.my.androidapp.MyPreferencesFragment" title="General Category >
        <extra android:name="resource" android:value="preferences_general" />
    </header>
    <header... one per category, different titles and extra values for each.
</preference-headers>
```

MyPreferenceFragment looks like this:

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String name = getArguments().getString("resource");
        int res = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(name, "xml", getActivity().getPackageName());
        addPreferencesFromResource(res);
```

And then finally, my preference file looks like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen blah...>
    <Preference android:fragment="com.my.androidapp.MyPreferenceFragment" android:title="Drill Down!">
        <extra android:name="resource" android:value="preferences_subgeneral" />
    </Preference>
    <Preference... whatever I want... I can use ordinary preferences or any number of items that can be selected to drill down further still.
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Hope this helps other people, particularly other people with massive amounts of preferences.

Comment: I'm currently stuck since I also want a multi tier settings in my App. Of course it is possible to do it like you suggested but in my case, when I open the App on a Tablet, the left side shows my top level settings and the right side shows the detailed settings for the selected top level item.

When I now chose an item to open the third level of the settings, it's opened in fullscreen and the ActionBar is gone.

Is there a way to just replace the right side content of the split pane or at least show the ActionBar? Or is this completely agains the Android design rules? :/